# ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'. Getting error while running docker compose up

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, jinja2

I have the following Dockerfile and docker-compose respectively:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app

CMD python main.py
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8001:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7.41
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: main
      MYSQL_USER: root_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root_user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33067:3306
```

and **requirements.txt**:

```
jinja2<3.1.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
Flask-Migrate==2.5.3
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-Cors==3.0.9
requests==2.25.0
mysqlclient==2.0.1
pika==1.1.0
```

I added jinja2<3.1.0 after reading that jinja2 removed the escape class in the 3.1.0 version.
But I am getting the same error when running the backend service.

```
main_app-backend-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):

main_app-backend-1  |   File "/app/main.py", line 1, in \<module\>

main_app-backend-1  |     from flask import Flask

main_app-backend-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/\__init_\_.py", line 14, in \<module\>

main_app-backend-1  |     from jinja2 import escape

main_app-backend-1  | ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/\__init_\_.py)

main_app-backend-1 exited with code 1
```

**Has anyone encountered something similar?**

Answer (score 0):

What version of `jinja2` is actually installed? If I `pip install 'jinja2<3.1.0'`, I get version 3.0.3, and `jinja2.escape` appears to exist in that version:

```
root@d7f369c74abd:/# pip install 'jinja2<3.1.0'
Collecting jinja2<3.1.0
  Downloading Jinja2-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.6/133.6 kB 4.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, jinja2
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.3 jinja2-3.0.3
root@d7f369c74abd:/# python
Python 3.9.18 (main, Dec 19 2023, 20:58:27)
[GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jinja2
>>> jinja2.escape("hello world")
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: 'jinja2.escape' is deprecated and will be removed in Jinja 3.1. Import 'markupsafe.escape' instead.
Markup('hello world')
```

Note that the `escape` method has not been removed in more recent versions; it has simply been relocated to the `jinja2.filters` package. With version 3.1.2 (the current release):

```
root@479c2978e931:/# pip install jinja2
Collecting jinja2
  Downloading Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.1/133.1 kB 3.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, jinja2
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.3 jinja2-3.1.2
root@479c2978e931:/# python
Python 3.9.18 (main, Dec 19 2023, 20:58:27)
[GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jinja2.filters
>>> jinja2.filters.escape("hello world")
Markup('hello world')
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply.
I actually modified my requirements.txt file and emptied it. But the error still persisted.

Comment: So, what versions of Jinja2 is getting installed?

Comment: Also, yes escape method exists in the 3.0.3 version. That is the reason I was trying to downgrade my jinja2 version in order to make it compatible with the current Flask version I am using.

Comment: I don't see what version is getting installed. When i try to run the backend service by running docker-compose up, I get the import error itself.

Comment: Just open a python interactive prompt in the container, and then `import jinja2` followed by `jinja2.__version__`. You may need to modify your container so that it doesn't exit immediately with an error (e.g., run `sleep inf` instead of `python main.py` or something).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help \n
>>> import jinja2
>>> jinja2.__version__
'3.1.2'
That is the output I'm getting. Looks like it installs the 3.1.2 afterall

Comment: What does the output of the `pip install` command look like when you run build your image? Run `docker build` with `--progress=plain` to see the complete output. When I build using your Dockerfile I get version 3.0.3 as expected.

Comment: I retried building it and i am getting 3.0.3 version also. I mistakely used the previous image which had no mention of jinja2 while running the first time.

Comment: Also, now when I run python main.py inside the shell, now I am getting a different error.
ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/itsdangerous/__init__.py)